# Using ConfigurationProperties to fill Map using application property

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class PartnerService {
        
    private PartnerData partnerData  = new PartnerData();
    
    public void setPartnerData(PartnerData partnerData) {
        this.partnerData = partnerData;
    }
    
    public PartnerData getPartnerData() {
        return partnerData;
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("partner.cred")
    public static class PartnerData {
    
        private Map<String, PartnerCredential> data = new HashMap<>();

        public Map<String, PartnerCredential> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Map<String, PartnerCredential> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }
    
    public class PartnerCredential {

        private String clientId;
        private String clientSecret;
        
        public PartnerCredential() {
            
        }

        public String getClientId() {
            return clientId;
        }

        public String getClientSecret() {
            return clientSecret;
        }
        
        
        public void setClientId(String clientId) {
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        public void setClientSecret(String clientSecret) {
            this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        }

    }
```

I have to set the value in the application property

```
partner.cred.data={\
key: {clientId : 'id', clientSecret : 'secret'}\
}
```

Map.get("key") is throwing NPE the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null.

I saw and tried to implement suggestion to similar questions, but I am not sure what is wrong, I am guessing the syntax is wrong in the property file but I am not sure what.

Comment: was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

set your application.property file like this:

```
partner:
    cred:
       data:
          key: 
            clientId : id
            clientSecret : secret
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the nullpointer-issue is due to the fact that your service is not aware of PartnerData.

To solve this problem (and avoid circular dependency):

- Extract `PartnerData` in a separate configuration-class
- Wire `PartnerData` in the service, preferably via constructor injection
- Insert PartnerData in your `application.properties`

This should look something like:

Configuration properties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "partner.cred")
public class PartnerData {

    private Map<String, PartnerCredential> data = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, PartnerCredential> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static class PartnerCredential {

        private String clientId;
        private String clientSecret;

        //getters and setters
        ...
    }
}
```

The Service

```
@Configuration
class PartnerService {

    private final PartnerData partnerData;

    // constructor injection
    public PartnerService(PartnerData partnerData) {
        this.partnerData = partnerData;
    }

    public PartnerData getPartnerData() {
        return partnerData;
    }

}
```

application.properties where `one` and `two` are the keys of the map

```
partner.cred.data.one.clientId=1
partner.cred.data.one.clientSecret=secret_1

partner.cred.data.two.clientId=2
partner.cred.data.two.clientSecret=secret_2
```